# Can't assign HTML to HTMLDocument.body

Tags: c#, .net, mshtml

I wanted to use `HTMLDocument` object from `mshtml` library. I was trying to assign HTML to document:

```
var doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
var html = File.ReadAllText(@"path_to_html_file");
doc.body.innerHTML = html; // <-- this line throws error
```

However, I get error on the third line:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>   mshtml.DispHTMLDocument.body.get returned null.

I was trying to use dynamic code, but it didn't work either:

```
dynamic doc = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("htmlfile"));
```

In this case I get the following error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

Is there some solution to overcome this problem? Thanks!

#### UPDATE: VBA code

```vb
Sub GetData()
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, txt As TextStream

    Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("path_to_html_file")
    doc.body.innerHTML = txt.ReadAll() '// <-- No error here
    txt.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Are  you sure  the path to the file is   valid?

Comment: @preciousbetine The problem is *not* with the file.

Comment: @preciousbetine I used same code in VBA (adjusted to it) - and it works perfectly.

Comment: It seems like your document `body` property is null. Why are you trying to create a new document instead of referencing the `doc` variable to existing doc?

Comment: @ymz Yes, I know that the problem is that `body` is `null`. The question is - why it works in VBA, but doesn't work in C#.

Comment: Can you post your `VBA` code as well? (relevant parts of-course)

Comment: @ymz I have added VBA code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the **`mshtml.HtmlDocument`** to the [IHTMLDocument2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v%3Dvs.85)) interface, to have the main objects' properties and methods available:

```
var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
```

Or create a **`HtmlDocumentClass`** instance using `Activator.CreateInstance()` with the Type Guid, then cast to a `IHTMLDocument2` Interface.

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = 
   (IHTMLDocument2)Activator.CreateInstance(
       Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13")));
```

It's more or less the same thing. I'ld prefer the first one, mainly [for this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171569/7444103)

Then you can write to the `HtmlDocument` whatever you want. For example:

```
doc.write(File.ReadAllText(@"[Some Html Page]"));
Console.WriteLine(doc.body.innerText);
```

To create a HtmlDocument, a skeleton HTML Page is enough, something like this:

```
string html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><Body><p></body></html>";
doc.write(html);
```

**Note: before a Document is created, all elements in the page will be `null`**.

After, you can set the `Body.InnerHtml` to something else:

```
doc.body.innerHTML = "<P>Some Text</P>";
Console.WriteLine(doc.body.innerText);
```

Note that if you need to work with HTML Document more extensively, you'll have to cast to a higher level interface: [`IHTMLDocument3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752541(v%3dvs.85)) to [`IHTMLDocument8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj191946(v%3Dvs.85)) (as of now), depeding on the System version.

The classic [`getElementById`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752543(v%3Dvs.85)), [`getElementsByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752544(v%3Dvs.85)), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752545(v%3Dvs.85)) methods are availble in the **`IHTMLDocument3`** interface.

For example, use the **`getElementsByTagName()`** to retrieve the `InnerText` of an **`HTMLElement`** using it's tag name:

```
string innerText = 
   (doc as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByTagName("body")
                          .OfType<IHTMLElement>().First().inne‌​rText;
```

**Note**:
If you can't find the **`IHTMLDocument6`**, **`IHTMLDocument7`** and **`IHTMLDocument8`** interfaces (and possibly other interfaces referenced in the MSDN Docs), then you probably have an old Type library in the `\Windows\Assembly\` `GAC`. Follow Hans Passant's advices to create a new **`Interop.mshtml`** library:
[How to get mshtml.IHTMLDocument6 or mshtml.IHTMLDocument7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588380/7444103)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately IntelliSense shows maximum version `IHTMLDocument5` - and this version doesn't have neither `body` property nor `getElementById` method. Also, the `Activator.CreateInstance` didn't help either - error says that `body` is null.

Comment: Cast to `IHtmlDocument2`, as shown in the example. The other interfaces offer different methods and properties. See the Docs about what's available per Interface.

Comment: Although `IHtmlDocument2` supports `body`, but it's null again. Moreover, it doesn't support `getElementById`! :)

Comment: I guess, I need to stick with VBA or use HtmlAgilityPack :)

Comment: What System and Framework/mshtml versions are you using?. This is quite a classic setup. + Did you `.write` to the doc before setting anything? Do you have a `using mshtml;` in code?

Comment: Note, from the sample code, that `Body` is `null` unless you write some HTML into the Document. You can't set the Body to anything if the Document doesn't contain an HTML page. A simple skeleton of the page (which should start with `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> (...)`) is enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187392/discussion-between-johnyl-and-jimi).

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the System.NullReferenceException too, because the doc.body was null. Finally, I resolved the problem in this way:

```
   public void SetWebBrowserHtml(WebBrowser webBrowser, string html)
    {
        if (!(webBrowser.Document is MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2))
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
        }
        if (webBrowser.Document is MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 doc)
        {
            if (doc.body == null)
            {
                doc.write(html);
            }
            else
            {
                doc.body.innerHTML = html;
            }
        }
    }
```