# When should we use tlbimp.exe instead of "normal" DLLs?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, dll, tlbimp

my question relates to the program tlbimp.exe and its generation of DLLs.

We have been working with DLLs from a specific SDK for some time. (PDFXChange Editor SDK to be exact) And we work with VB.NET on Visual Studio.

So far, the associated DLL files (which are also executed in the unmanaged code) have simply been integrated and used.

Now I have seen that the SDK contains TLB files in addition to the .DLL files.

Then I became aware of tlbimp.exe.

The question I am asking myself is: What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the DLLs generated by tlbimp?

We have never used tlbimp before. And now I would like to find out whether it would be better to use tlbimp in the future or whether the advantages of "normal" DLLs outweigh them.

I thank you in advance :)

Comment: [Tlbimp.exe (Type Library Importer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer): *The Type Library Importer converts the type definitions found within a COM type library into equivalent definitions in a common language runtime assembly.*

Comment: Thanks :) But I already know about this Link. Unfortunately, the link does not answer me what advantages result from using it. I mean, our DLLs worked that way all the time. That's why I'm wondering in which scenario tlbimp would be needed.

Comment: This is one of the reason I use it: [How to get mshtml.IHTMLDocument6 or mshtml.IHTMLDocument7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588380/7444103). I can't say whether you might have *advantages* in your context.

Comment: Adding a reference to the DLL is usually good enough to use the type library that is embedded inside the DLL.  But it requires the component to be installed and its type library to convert cleanly without warnings.  So tlbimp.exe is *required* on a build server whose owner wants to keep it clean or support building for different versions.  c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll is a good example of a DLL with an embedded type library that can't convert cleanly.