# MSHTML DLL very slow to load at startup

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mshtml, microsoft.mshtml

I have a fairly large VB.NET WinForms project which loaded fine until recently.  I have no recollection of any major changes in the startup code and I can only think of recent VS2019 upgrades that may have had an impact on the dev environment.

Here below is the Debug Output with the last line causing problem.
Thanks in advance

> 'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\TWS API 976\samples\VB\soap_may3rd\soap\SoapCore\bin\Debug\Soap.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\TWS API 976\samples\VB\soap_may3rd\soap\SoapCore\bin\Debug\InteractiveBrokers.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Management.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The thread 0x176c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded 'C:\TWS API 976\samples\VB\soap_may3rd\soap\SoapCore\bin\Debug\MathNet.Numerics.dll'. 
>   ReqCore done
>   The thread 0x5ccc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'Soap.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Soap.exe): Loaded **'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.mshtml.dll'. Module was built without symbols.**

Comment: In your project where you add reference to `mshtm`, do you enable the `EmbedInteropTypes` property? Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29745796/10216583).

Comment: Try rebuilding it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588380/7444103), see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  I first removed the mshtml reference and it made no difference.  I added it again from the PIA folder, and again no difference. Removed it again and added the one provided with VS which seems more recent: no difference.
I set EmbedInteropType to False and Copy Local to True.

Comment: I also tried importing the MSHTML TLB file but it was already andquite a few other warnings came up.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515311/10216583) out. Don't skip the comments.

Comment: Thanks JQSOFT. I read the link you provided and checked the comments most of which go way beyond my level...   I have so far tried with and without an explicit reference, tried the DLL from VS as well as the other one in Windows\System32 and I have no idea how to debug this further.